# How to check if Windows Address Book or Windows Contacts is installed

Tags: windows, contacts, addressbook

Does anybody know where in registry I can check and see if either of these applications are installed on the machine:

- Windows address book
- Windows Contacts

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft:  I know it says win 95, but the reg is the same.

Internet Mail and News
The Windows Address Book used by Internet Mail and News is located in the Windows folder. The Address Book file is named .wab, where  is the name with which you log on to Windows 95. If you do not have a logon name for Windows 95, the default name for the file is UserMPS.wab.

To move the Address Book file, drag the .wab file from the Windows folder to a different location on the hard drive.

To rename the Address Book file, right-click the .wab file, click Rename on the menu that appears, type a new name for the file, and then press the ENTER key.

If you move or rename the address book file, you must update the following registry key to point to the file's new name or location:

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WAB\Wab File Name\(Default)
```

NOTE: The Windows Address Book is not designed to be run on a server. If multiple users attempt to access the file, problems may result.